# labels showing up behind other labels due to unmatched z-index

Tags: leaflet, labeling, z-index

I am using leaflet label plugin to show labels on markers by using `layer.bindLabel('name')`. As the number of markers is high the markers come above the label thus labels are not visible clearly. [image]

Seems marker and its label have same z-index. I tried changing the z-index of marker by `.leaflet-marker-icon{ z-index: 1000;}` and also that of the label `.lealet-label{z-index: 1001;}` but still the result is the same and the z-index of marker is not changed either. What would be solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK the label of a feature has by default [the same z-index than the marker](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label/issues/28) and the "correct" way to change the z-index of a marker is with the constructor option [zIndexOffset](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-zindexoffset) or the method [setZIndexOffset](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-setzindexoffset).

Comment: In the marker, you can set riseOnHover =true.

Comment: neogeomat's solution (set riseOnHover=true in the marker) worked perfectly for me!